# can't create persistent store coordinator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data

I am getting the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyExprojectception', reason: 'Managed object store failed to create persistent store coordinator: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134130.)" UserInfo=0x6eb53f0 {URL=/Users/user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/4EFD7570-AD87-48E8-8606-1D5633F65AD9/Documents/DiscussionBoard.sqlite, metadata=<CFBasicHash 0x6e7b610 [0x1957400]>{type = immutable dict, count = 7,
entries =>
    2 : <CFString 0x6e7bc80 [0x1957400]>{contents = "NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers"} = <CFArray 0x6e7bd60 [0x1957400]>{type = immutable, count = 1, values = (
    0 : <CFString 0x194eed0 [0x1957400]>{contents = ""}
)}
    4 : <CFString 0x6e7bcb0 [0x1957400]>{contents = "NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion"} = <CFNumber 0x6e7b820 [0x1957400]>{value = +320, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
    6 : <CFString 0x6e7bce0 [0x1957400]>{contents = "NSStoreModelVersionHashes"} = <CFBasicHash 0x6e7c310 [0x1957400]>{type = immutable dict, count = 13,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x6e7bd80 [0x1957400]>{contents = "CVImage"} = <CFData 0x6e7bf00 [0x1957400]>{length = 32, capacity = 32, bytes = 0xbd556295681226e6b1fd6142e2e7bfcc ... e38b423dd3965969}
    2 : <CFString 0x6e7bda0 [0x1957400]>{contents = "CVMembers"} = <CFData 0x6e7bf50 [0x1957400]>{length = 32, capacity = 32, bytes = 0xa3d504782e9111ed01b1c02575c48119 ... 1bd1d59e42507652}
    4 : <CFString 0x6e7bdc0 [0x1957400]>{contents = "CVMessages"} = <CFData 0x6e7bfa0 [0x1957400]>{length = 32, capacity = 32, bytes = 0xfbd5da9b0fc0ea188505807aea912e83 ... e3a42fa8fbdf416c}
    8 : <CFString 0x6e7bde0 [0x1957400]>{contents = "CVEmbed"} = <CFData 0x6e7bff0 [0x1957400]>{length = 32, capacity = 32, bytes = 0x5d65d864e7881875c52882a8fd709079 ... e3ad8204d4ca3de3}
    9 : <CFString 0x6e7be00 [0x1957400]>{contents = "CVGroup"} = <CFData 0x6e7c040 [0x1957400]>{length = 32, capacity = 32, bytes = 0xb2989b51004a22a8fb78971436462bcc ... 39d14fd18d892843}
    10 : <CFString 0x6e7be20 [0x1957400]>{contents = "CVImgur"} = <CFData 0x6e7c090 [0x1957400]>{length = 32, capacity = 32, bytes = 0x57cb45112309b9fce595cbee14c87e98 ... f88cd7d4eadeb9aa}
    12 : <CFString 0x6e7be40 [0x1957400]>{contents = "CVLinks"} = <CFData 0x6e7c0e0 [0x1957400]>{length = 32, capacity = 32, bytes = 0x715c27157179226a0a44cd0015b9017d ... 26a06c18c21630d3}
    13 : <CFString 0x6e7b7c0 [0x1957400]>{contents = "CVStar"} = <CFData 0x6e7c130 [0x1957400]>{length = 32, capacity = 32, bytes = 0xeaba2443e38c48975f8e1eda97788ce3 ... 6939185adf9f8bc4}
    14 : <CFString 0x6e7be60 [0x1957400]>{contents = "CVLogin"} = <CFData 0x6e7c180 [0x1957400]>{length = 32, capacity = 32, bytes = 0x3089c83eba00f29b13543cdfa16514d7 ... db609adb46524cab}
    16 : <CFString 0x6e7be80 [0x1957400]>{contents = "CVTopics"} = <CFData 0x6e7c1d0 [0x1957400]>{length = 32, capacity = 32, bytes = 0x6ba8c6c71281ae9f3731a180cb0509cb ... 3aedf32173e19adf}
    17 : <CFString 0x6e7bea0 [0x1957400]>{contents = "CVConversation"} = <CFData 0x6e7c220 [0x1957400]>{length = 32, capacity = 32, bytes = 0xac552b4d9d0a2c0425facda397d0f3c1 ... 8a7b7d36c9a14af3}
    20 : <CFString 0x6e7bec0 [0x1957400]>{contents = "CVMessage"} = <CFData 0x6e7c270 [0x1957400]>{length = 32, capacity = 32, bytes = 0x80e0118b52f9679904a359ce469b116a ... ad08d1f238e71130}
    21 : <CFString 0x6e7bee0 [0x1957400]>{contents = "CVTopic"} = <CFData 0x6e7c2c0 [0x1957400]>{length = 32, capacity = 32, bytes = 0xe1898a56a02e523bc8879e812cecd756 ... 339f8023561d35f9}
}

    7 : <CFString 0x7888b0 [0x1957400]>{contents = "NSStoreUUID"} = <CFString 0x6e7b970 [0x1957400]>{contents = "BDA8B03E-81DA-472C-8966-936DC080900F"}
    8 : <CFString 0x788720 [0x1957400]>{contents = "NSStoreType"} = <CFString 0x7888f0 [0x1957400]>{contents = "SQLite"}
    9 : <CFString 0x6e7bd10 [0x1957400]>{contents = "NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion"} = <CFNumber 0x5f70a40 [0x1957400]>{value = +3, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    10 : <CFString 0x6e7bd40 [0x1957400]>{contents = "_NSAutoVacuumLevel"} = <CFString 0x6e7c410 [0x1957400]>{contents = "2"}
}
, reason=Can't find model for source store}'
```

It says can't find model for source store? What does this mean?

The code is:

```
- (void)createPersistentStoreCoordinator {
    NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.pathToStoreFile];

    NSError *error;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:_managedObjectModel];

    // Allow inferred migration from the original version of the application.
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error]) {
        if (self.delegate != nil && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(managedObjectStore:didFailToCreatePersistentStoreCoordinatorWithError:)]) {
            [self.delegate managedObjectStore:self didFailToCreatePersistentStoreCoordinatorWithError:error];
        } else {
            NSAssert(NO, @"Managed object store failed to create persistent store coordinator: %@", error); //fails right here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also post the code that raises this exception.

Comment: sorry, I posted the code above.. it fails on the NSAssert

Comment: Have you tried searching for this error phrase on google?  If so what things did you try?

Comment: As I just got this error recently after modifying the xcdatamodeld, so I guess I made some error there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things you should check:

- Be sure you have loaded your context correctly, and the .momd file is added to your app bundle
- Be sure your entity is named 'store' in the datamodel visual editor

Also, when dealing with CoreData there is a interesting userinfo which holds much useful informations:

```
NSDictionary *ui = [error userInfo];
        for(NSString *err in [ui keyEnumerator]) {
            NSLog(@"err:%@",[ui objectForKey:err]);
        }
```

Answer (score 16):

I noticed you are using RestKit, and I had this problem before, and solved it by removing my SqlLite database.  For me, it was when I added a new relationship and the database didn't like the new attribute.

Note: this works fine in development, but in Production you will need to perform a Core Data migration usually, as users won't want their data lost (depending on your application).

Answer (score 8):

Yes, I agree with firetoast. The problem disappears for me when I simply delete my application from the device/emulator and reinstall. This normally happens to me after I edit my core data schema and use restkit to persist.

Answer (score 0):

NSAssert is doing an assertion on whether or not a statement is true.  By passing in NO to it, you are making it so that it will always fail the assertion check.  I am assuming this is to force a hard fail if the previous if statement is false.

Comment: yes that is true, so how do I solve this? so it basically means that either the delegate is nil or it doesn't respond to the selector I specified?

Comment: I am not certain - I have not had this error in the past.  Is this generated code then that you are posting here?  Or is it code that you wrote or took from another source (i.e. a library or something similar)?