# can't add sql file while adding core data to my project

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I'm stuck trying to add Core Data to my existing iOS project. I don't have an existing sql database but I created a data model. I followed the following tutorial: http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2009/12/adding-core-data-existing-iphone-projects/

It produces an error at the following code:

```
(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *) persistentStoreCoordinator{
if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil){
    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentDirectory]
           stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"MyPOC.sqlite"]];
NSError *error = nil;
persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]
                              initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error]){
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error OH NO %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}
return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
2012-10-25 13:52:29.156 MyPOC[1994:11603] Unresolved error OH NO Error
Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The operation couldn’t be completed. 
(Cocoa error 512.)" UserInfo=0x8246240 {reason=Failed to create file; code = 2}, 
{reason = "Failed to create file; code = 2";}
```

I really have no idea why it crashes and how I can resolve it. If more information is needed to help please let me know.

Comment: check accepted answer for this question : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848394/cant-create-persistent-store-coordinator

Comment: You should check the value of `storeUrl`. The error code most probably means that the directory in which you want to create the SQLite file does not exist.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was following nearly the same tutorial and receiving the same error message.  I figured out what the problem is though.

In my case, the file could not be created because the storeURL path was incorrect and pointing to a folder that didn't exist.

In my helper method [self applicationDocumentDirectory] (which you did not provide in your question) I typed in the sample code just like in the tutorial:

```
- (NSString *) applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}
```

which produced the URL `file:///Users/xxxxxx/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/A6FDD8DB-475B-4C9B-B995-28CCE068DF82/`**Library/Documentation**`/`

There is a silly code completion typo in there which generates an invalid path.  Can you see it?

> It's the enum NSDocumentationDirectory for the NSSearchPathDirectory input parameter, it should be NSDocumentDirectory instead.

The correct code and URL is:

```
- (NSString *) applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject;
}
```

URL: `file:///Users/xxxxxx/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/A6FDD8DB-475B-4C9B-B995-28CCE068DF82/`**Documents**`/`

Comment: I found my old code somewhere stored on my pc and looked into it. You are totally correct! Good one to spot the error!

Comment: Sufferin' succotash! Nice spot. For those who’s eyes are as blurry as mine from working on iCloud matters:
NSDocumentDirectory (NOT NSDocumentationDirectory). Thanks.

Comment: Excellent catch. This is actually still in Apple's official core data documentation to this day, and is still a blatant error.

Answer (score 0):

to close this question.
i started a new core data project and imported my other code and it worked. Never got it to work in other project. Probably forgot something but did not find what